# Registering at hotel, one person does not have proper ID

Tags: uk, bookings, identity-cards

I am trying to book a hotel in Oxford, UK. I have been informed by my travel agent that the Holiday Inn needs my partner's exact name on their passport or drivers license, she has neither, any suggestions?

Comment: No other photo ID?

Comment: Is your partner from the UK? Is she going to be turning up on her own to take the room, or will the booking be in your name?

Comment: It's unlikely that the travel agent has ever been to a Holiday Inn. If your partner is a UK resident, then no ID will be required.

Comment: The hotel business would go bankrupt if they made all the women guests show ID.

Comment: A load of old balls.  Have your friend go to the Registry Office and get the long form birth certificate.  Assuming she is a Brit.

Comment: My suggestion would be that you find a different hotel.

Comment: If it's out of term, skip the Holiday Inn - it's not great and it's not in a great location! Just stay [in one of the Oxford colleges](http://www.universityrooms.com/en/city/oxford/home) - much nicer and more interesting rooms for your money!

Answer (score 3):

According to [The Immigration (Hotel Records) Order 1972](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1972/1689/article/4/made)

> 4.—(1) Every person of or over the age of 16 years who stays at any premises to which this Order applies shall, on arriving at the
>   premises, inform the keeper of the premises of his full name and
>   nationality.
>
> (2) Every such person who is an alien shall also—
>
> (a)on arriving at the premises, inform the keeper of the premises of
>   the number and place of issue of his passport, certificate of
>   registration or other document establishing his identity and
>   nationality

Since the OP's partner has neither a passport nor driving licence, and presumably no other national identity document, this indicates that they are likely to be a UK citizen who does not need to provide identification according to law. However, the hotel may have more stringent conditions. I find this unlikely since UK citizens do not require identity cards, and may not drive.

It is likely that the hotel will ask for a passport or driving licence if the occupant provides a foreign address since the assumption will be that they are not UK citizens. Providing a UK home address will usually prevent this being an issue.